# Checking for non-null (or null) result set for Firebird with PHP5

Tags: php, database, firebird, interbase

So, I haven't used firebird for that long, but i'm writing a search engine for a database we have.  There is a field that required you to ask for a reason the record was changed if you edit the record for some reason.  If the user fails to input this reason, I mark it in another table, to keep track of it all.

So, in my search results, I query this second table, and I'm trying to check for a non null (no one entered a reason for change) result set.  However, I've tried using both ibase_query and ibase_fetch_row return results, and it doesn't work as expected.

I've been going off of the php manual, and it says they should return TRUE (for ibase_query) or FALSE (for ibase_fetch_row) if the result set has nothing.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.ibase-query.php
http://php.net/manual/en/function.ibase-fetch-row.php

Here is the code for the ibase_fetch_row:

```
$query3 = "Select CHANGE_REASON from REASON_FOR_CHANGES where id = $id";
$result3 = ibase_query($link, $query3);

if (ibase_fetch_row($result3) != FALSE) {
   $reasonChange = "<span style='color:red'>".
       "No Reason Given. <a href='changeReason.php?id=$id'>Add Reason</a></span>";
}
```

And for ibase_query:

```
$query3 = "Select CHANGE_REASON from REASON_FOR_CHANGES where id = $id";
$result3 = ibase_query($link, $query3);

if ($result3 == TRUE) {
   $reasonChange = "<span style='color:red'>".
       "No Reason Given. <a href='changeReason.php?id=$id'>Add Reason</a></span>";
}
```

Anyone have any clue what I'm doing wrong?  It seems like the returns from the two functions aren't as documented.

Comment: Both your code samples are identical

Comment: Whoops, copied the wrong code over to SO.  Fixed the typo.  But the == was still correct.  Cant seem to figure out why this wont work the way it's advertised.